# Leoxsys USB WiFi device not deteting in ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, usb

I have bought a  [**Leoxsys WiFi USB device**](http://www.flipkart.com/leoxsys-leo-nano150n-usb-adapter/p/itmdnc4gcgh6dheh) to use WiFi in my PC. Its working absolutely fine in Windows7 as its provided with windows7 Drivers. Installing and using drivers in windows 7 is easy and Its working fine.

But coming to Ubuntu linux 12.04LTS its not working . Actually I found drivers for all OS's in Device's official site. Here is the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l791n9foh1nm91w/AP%20adapter.zip) . But they did not provide any guide to how to install those drivers in linux. I am new to Ubuntu, can any one help regarding this. I want create WiFi hotspot with it. I tried aphotspot and some tutorials on the web, nothing worked.

Can any know the solution for my problem.

Comment: If the problem is not fixed can u provide me your teminal output of : lsusb

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
2. Change to the extracted directory: `cd ~/Downloads/Realtek\ Ap\ Adapt/driver/Linux`. (You have to replace this by the path on your system)
3. Allow the installer to be executed: `chmod +x install.sh`
4. Run the installer as root: `sudo ./install.sh`

If any errors occure, add them to your question, if you can't fix them on your own.

Comment: I did the same what you said, its throwing me follwing error, I hosen option 1 and entered root password, but following error. Please select card type(1/2):
1) RTL8188eus
2) RTL8189es
#? 1)
You have selected 
Unknown NIC type
Authentication requested [root] for make clean:
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 1
Please check error Mesg
##################################################

Comment: Then do `sudo -s`, enter your password, and then run `./install.sh`

Comment: I tried with sudo -s .. Same error man

Comment: Could you please **add** the error to **your question**. (Click the edit button.) Please format it as code. (the `<?>` button in the editor.)